# Setting arguments from a text file does not work

Tags: shell-script, zenity, set

Here is my code.

```
  #!/bin/bash

  set -- $(cat /home/jeevan/tempzen1.txt)
  zenity "$@"
```

file tempzen1.txt contains : --list --title FILE-SELECTOR --column serialno. --column file --width 1000 --height 600 --radiolist TRUE "/home/jeevan/very very latest"

Why does not the above code work when the below works?
I simply wrote set args inside my script and started zenity from within the same script, then it works, but why not from another text file?

this is my working code:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -- --list --title "FILE SELECTOR" --column serialno. --column file --width 1000 --height 600 --radiolist TRUE "/home/jeevan/very very latest"
zenity "$@"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the same problem as in your previous question - parameter `$@` contains only one argument, namely `--list --title "FILE SELECTOR" --column serialno. --column file --width 1000 --height 600 --radiolist TRUE "/home/jeevan/very very latest"` (yes the whole part is one argument including spaces, quotes etc.), whereas you want to split it and pass several arguments.

And again solution is to `eval`uate the command:

```
set -- "$(cat /home/jeevan/tempzen1.txt)"
eval zenity "$@"
```

or even better directly:

```
eval zenity "$(cat /home/jeevan/tempzen1.txt)"
```